# shapely interpolate in three dimensions returns Point Z but invalid results

Tags: python, shapely

I am trying to use interpolate along a three dimensional line. However, any changes in the Z axis are not taken into account by .interpolate.

```
LineString([(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2)]).interpolate(1, normalized=True).wkt
'POINT Z (0 0 0)'
```

vs

```
LineString([(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0)]).interpolate(1, normalized=True).wkt
'POINT Z (0 2 0)'
```

I read the documentation and it is silent on 3D lines or the restriction is documented at a higher level than the interpolate documentation.

Is this a bug? I can't believe I'm the first person to try this.

Assuming that there is no direct way to accomplish this, any suggestions for doing my own interpolation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone asked me " Can you interpolate along each axis instead of doing all three together?" I think the answer is yes and here is the approach I used.

```
# Upsample to 1S intervals rather than our desired interval because resample throws
# out rows that do not fall on the desired interval, including the rows we want to keep.
int_df = df.resample('1S', origin='start').asfreq()

# For each axis, interpolate to fill in NAN values.

int_df['Latitude'] = int_df['Latitude'].interpolate(method='polynomial', order=order)
int_df['Longitude'] = int_df['Longitude'].interpolate(method='polynomial', order=order)
int_df['AGL'] = int_df['AGL'].interpolate(method='polynomial', order=order)


# Now downsample to our desired frequency
int_df = int_df.resample('5S', origin='start').asfreq()
```

I initially resampled at 5S intervals but that caused any existing points that were not on the interval boundaries to get dropped in favor of new ones that were on the interval boundaries. For my use case this is important. If you want regular intervals then you don't need to upsample then down sample.

After that, just interpolate each of the three axis.

So, if I started with:

[image: original data]

I now have:

[image: interpolated data]

Answer (score 3):

That does indeed seem like a bug from shapely. I looked into the source code a little bit and I'm willing to bet it's an upstream issue with PyGEOS.

Anyways, here's a little implementation I put together:

```py
import numpy as np
import shapely
import geopandas as gpd # Only necessary for the examples, not the actual function

def my_interpolate(input_line, input_dist, normalized=False):
    '''
    Function that interpolates the coordinates of a shapely LineString.
    Note: If you use this function on a MultiLineString geometry, it will 
    "flatten" the geometry and consider all the points in it to be 
    consecutively connected. For example, consider the following shape: 
        MultiLineString(((0,0),(0,2)),((0,4),(0,6)))
    In this case, this function will assume that there is no gap between
    (0,2) and (0,4). Instead, the function will assume that these points
    all connected. Explicitly, the MultiLineString above will be 
    interpreted instead as the following shape:
        LineString((0,0),(0,2),(0,4),(0,6))

    Parameters
    ----------
    input_line : shapely.geometry.Linestring or shapely.geometry.MultiLineString
        (Multi)LineString whose coordinates you want to interpolate
    input_dist : float
        Distance used to calculate the interpolation point
    normalized : boolean
        Flag that indicates whether or not the `input_dist` argument should be
        interpreted as being an absolute number or a percentage that is 
        relative to the total distance or not.
        When this flag is set to "False", the `input_dist` argument is assumed 
        to be an actual absolute distance from the starting point of the 
        geometry. When this flag is set to "True", the `input_dist` argument 
        is assumed to represent the relative distance with respect to the 
        geometry's full distance.
        The default is False.

    Returns
    -------
    shapely.geometry.Point
        The shapely geometry of the interpolated Point.

    '''
    # Making sure the entry value is a LineString or MultiLineString
    if ((input_line.type.lower() != 'linestring') and 
        (input_line.type.lower() != 'multilinestring')):
        return None
    
    # Extracting the coordinates from the geometry
    if input_line.type.lower()[:len('multi')] == 'multi':
        # In case it's a multilinestring, this step "flattens" the points
        coords = [item for sub_list in [list(this_geom.coords) for 
                                        this_geom in input_line.geoms] 
                  for item in sub_list]
    else:
        coords = [tuple(coord) for coord in list(input_line.coords)]
    
    # Transforming the list of coordinates into a numpy array for 
    # ease of manipulation
    coords = np.array(coords)
    
    # Calculating the distances between points
    dists = ((coords[:-1] - coords[1:])**2).sum(axis=1)**0.5
    
    # Calculating the cumulative distances
    dists_cum = np.append(0,dists.cumsum())
    
    # Finding the total distance
    dist_total = dists_cum[-1]
    
    # Finding appropriate use of the `input_dist` value
    if normalized == False:
        input_dist_abs = input_dist
        input_dist_rel = input_dist / dist_total
    else:
        input_dist_abs = input_dist * dist_total
        input_dist_rel = input_dist
    
    # Taking care of some edge cases
    if ((input_dist_rel < 0) or 
        (input_dist_rel > 1) or 
        (input_dist_abs < 0) or 
        (input_dist_abs > dist_total)):
        return None
    elif ((input_dist_rel == 0) or (input_dist_abs == 0)):
        return shapely.geometry.Point(coords[0])
    elif ((input_dist_rel == 1) or (input_dist_abs == dist_total)):
        return shapely.geometry.Point(coords[-1])
    
    # Finding which point is immediately before and after the input distance
    pt_before_idx = np.arange(dists_cum.shape[0])[(dists_cum <= input_dist_abs)].max()
    pt_after_idx  = np.arange(dists_cum.shape[0])[(dists_cum >= input_dist_abs)].min()
    
    pt_before = coords[pt_before_idx]
    pt_after = coords[pt_after_idx]
    seg_full_dist = dists[pt_before_idx]
    dist_left = input_dist_abs - dists_cum[pt_before_idx]
    
    # Calculating the interpolated coordinates
    interpolated_coords = ((dist_left / seg_full_dist) * (pt_after - pt_before)) + pt_before
    
    # Creating a shapely geometry
    interpolated_point = shapely.geometry.Point(interpolated_coords)
    
    return interpolated_point
```

The function above can be used on Shapely (Multi)LineStrings. Here's an example of it being applied to a simple LineString.

```py
input_line = shapely.geometry.LineString([(0, 0, 0), 
                                          (1, 2, 3), 
                                          (4, 5, 6)])


interpolated_point = my_interpolate(input_line, 2.5, normalized=False)

print(interpolated_point.wkt)

> POINT Z (0.6681531047810609 1.336306209562122 2.004459314343183)
```

And here's an example of using the `apply` method to perform the interpolation on a whole GeoDataFrame of LineStrings:

```py
line_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'id':[1,
                                  2,
                                  3],
                            'geometry':[input_line,
                                        input_line,
                                        input_line],
                            'interpolate_dist':[0.5,
                                                2.5,
                                                6.5],
                            'interpolate_dist_normalized':[True,
                                                           False,
                                                           False]})

interpolated_points = line_df.apply(
    lambda row: my_interpolate(input_line=row['geometry'], 
                               input_dist=row['interpolate_dist'], 
                               normalized=row['interpolate_dist_normalized']),
    axis=1)

print(interpolated_points.apply(lambda point: point.wkt))

> 0    POINT Z (1.419876550265357 2.419876550265356 3...
> 1    POINT Z (0.6681531047810609 1.336306209562122 ...
> 2    POINT Z (2.592529850263281 3.592529850263281 4...
> dtype: object
```

## Important notes

### Corner cases and error handling

Please note that the function I developed doesn't do error handling very well. In many cases, it just silently returns a `None` object. Depending on your use case, you might want to adjust that behavior.

### MultiLineStrings

The function above can be used on MultiLineStrings, but it makes some simplifications and assumptions. If you use this function on a MultiLineString geometry, it will "flatten" the geometry and consider all the points in it to be consecutively connected. For example, consider the following shape:

`MultiLineString(((0,0),(0,2)),((0,4),(0,6)))`

In this case, the function will assume that there is no gap between (0,2) and (0,4). Instead, the function will assume that these points are all connected. Explicitly, the MultiLineString above will be interpreted instead as the following shape:

`LineString((0,0),(0,2),(0,4),(0,6))`

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of why the shapely manipulation functions are not operating on 3D / Z:

From [shapely docs](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#geometric-objects). (writing this when version 1.8.X is current)

> A third z coordinate value may be used when constructing instances,
> but has no effect on geometric analysis. All operations are performed
> in the x-y plane.

I also need Z for my purposes. So was searching for this information to see if using geopandas (which uses shaply) was an option, rather then osgeo.ogr.